NDSolve for two layers domain
I want to solve the following system of equations using NDSolve.

where prime symbol (') denotes the derivative w.r.t. the variable y. I want to plot the result in a single graph over the domain [0,1] for two values of one parameter, say k1. I am trying with the following piece of code.
h = 0.3; k1 = 5.0; k2 = 10.0; eps = 1.0; Q = 0.2; sd = 0.5; ss = 0.06; sf = 0.001;
sys2 = {s2''[y] == k2*k2*s2[y]};
iv2 = {s2[0] == sf, s2[h] == sd + s1[h]};
sys1 = {s1''[y] == k1*k1*s1[y]};
iv1 = {s1[1] == ss, s1'[h] == (eps*s2'[h]) - Q};
sol[k1_] := NDSolve[Join[sys1,iv1,sys2,iv2], s == s1 + s2, {y, 0, 1}];
P1 = Evaluate[Table[s'[y] /. sol[k1], {k1 = 5}]];
P2 = Evaluate[Table[s'[y] /. sol[k1], {k1 = 10}]];
Plot[{P1, P2}, {y, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {y, s},
  Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> {{Line, Magenta}, {Line, Blue}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"k1 = 5 ", "k1 = 10 "}, Center]]

Any help with the code will be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

We can use Module to compute parametric solution as follows
sol[k_] := 
  Module[{h = 0.3, k2 = 10.0, eps = 1.0, Q = 0.2, sd = 0.5, ss = 0.06,
     sf = 0.001, k1 = k}, sys2 = {s2''[y] == k2*k2*s2[y]};
   iv2 = {s2[0] == sf, s2[h] == sd + s1[h]};
   sys1 = {s1''[y] == k1*k1*s1[y]};
   iv1 = {s1[1] == ss, s1'[h] == (eps*s2'[h]) - Q}; 
   soln = NDSolve[Join[sys1, iv1, sys2, iv2], {s1, s2}, {y, 0, 1}]; 
   soln[[1]]];

Visualization
Plot[Evaluate[Table[(s1'[y] + s2'[y]) /. sol[k], {k, {.5, 10}}]], {y, 
  0, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"y", "s"}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> {{Line, Magenta}, {Line, Blue}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"k1 = 5 ", "k1 = 10 "}, Center]] 


Update 1. To plot s2(y) over 0<y<h and s1(y) over h<y<1 we use
Plot[Evaluate[
  Table[If[y <= 0.3, s1[y], s2[y]] /. sol[k], {k, {.5, 10}}]], {y, 0, 
  1}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"y", "s1, s2"}, 
 Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> {{Line, Magenta}, {Line, Blue}}, 
 PlotLegends -> Placed[{"k1 = 5 ", "k1 = 10 "}, Center]]



Thank you for your answer. Actually I want to plot s2(y) over 0<y<h and s1(y) over h<y<1 in a single graph. Could you please help me on the same.

@Dr.B.Mallick See Update 1.

DSolve[] will give a symbolic solution.
If you have set the parameters, you will need to clear them all. I didn't set them, because sometimes having approximate real floats messes with exact solvers like DSolve[]. Since DSolve[] is very fast below, there seemed no need to reconsider.
dsol = First@DSolve[Join[sys1, iv1, sys2, iv2], {s1, s2}, y]
(*
  {s1 -> Function[{y}, (E^(-k1 y) (-E^(2 k1 + h k1) Q + 
         E^(2 k1 + h k1 + 2 h k2) Q + E^(h k1 + 2 k1 y) Q - 
         E^(h k1 + 2 h k2 + 2 k1 y) Q - E^(2 k1 + h k1) eps k2 sd - 
         E^(2 k1 + h k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2 sd + E^(h k1 + 2 k1 y) eps k2 sd + 
         E^(h k1 + 2 h k2 + 2 k1 y) eps k2 sd + 2 E^(2 k1 + h k1 + h k2) eps k2 sf - 
         2 E^(h k1 + h k2 + 2 k1 y) eps k2 sf - 
         E^(k1 + 2 h k1) k1 ss + E^(k1 + 2 h k1 + 2 h k2) k1 ss - 
         E^(k1 + 2 k1 y) k1 ss + E^(k1 + 2 h k2 + 2 k1 y) k1 ss - 
         E^(k1 + 2 h k1) eps k2 ss - E^(k1 + 2 h k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2 ss + 
         E^(k1 + 2 k1 y) eps k2 ss + 
         E^(k1 + 2 h k2 + 2 k1 y) eps k2 ss))/(-E^(2 k1) k1 - 
       E^(2 h k1) k1 + E^(2 k1 + 2 h k2) k1 + E^(2 h k1 + 2 h k2) k1 +
        E^(2 k1) eps k2 - E^(2 h k1) eps k2 + 
       E^(2 k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2 - E^(2 h k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2)], 
   s2 -> Function[{y}, (E^(-k2 y) (-E^(2 k1 + h k2) Q + 
         E^(2 h k1 + h k2) Q + E^(2 k1 + h k2 + 2 k2 y) Q - 
         E^(2 h k1 + h k2 + 2 k2 y) Q - E^(2 k1 + h k2) k1 sd - 
         E^(2 h k1 + h k2) k1 sd + E^(2 k1 + h k2 + 2 k2 y) k1 sd + 
         E^(2 h k1 + h k2 + 2 k2 y) k1 sd + E^(2 k1 + 2 h k2) k1 sf + 
         E^(2 h k1 + 2 h k2) k1 sf - E^(2 k1 + 2 k2 y) k1 sf - 
         E^(2 h k1 + 2 k2 y) k1 sf + E^(2 k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2 sf - 
         E^(2 h k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2 sf + E^(2 k1 + 2 k2 y) eps k2 sf -
          E^(2 h k1 + 2 k2 y) eps k2 sf - 2 E^(k1 + h k1 + h k2) k1 ss + 
         2 E^(k1 + h k1 + h k2 + 2 k2 y) k1 ss))/(-E^(2 k1) k1 - 
       E^(2 h k1) k1 + E^(2 k1 + 2 h k2) k1 + E^(2 h k1 + 2 h k2) k1 +
        E^(2 k1) eps k2 - E^(2 h k1) eps k2 + 
       E^(2 k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2 - E^(2 h k1 + 2 h k2) eps k2)]}
*)

We can compare with @Alex Trounev's example as follows. I'll use a tool from my own toolbox for evaluating code from this site that begin with a gazillion parameter settings. It temporarily sets the parameters using Block[] so that they do not interfere with any other work I happen to be doing.
(* set parameters; `p` should have the form:
     a = 1.2; b = 3.4 ...  <-- CompoundExpression[] of Set[] assignments
*)
paramset[p_, code_] := (Function[c, Block[p, c], HoldAll] /. 
     CompoundExpression -> List)[code];

paramset[
 h = 0.3; k1 = 5.0; k2 = 10.0; eps = 1.0; Q = 0.2; sd = 0.5; 
 ss = 0.06; sf = 0.001,
 Plot[Evaluate[Table[(s1'[y] + s2'[y]) /. dsol, {k1, {.5, 10}}]], {y, 
   0, 1}, PlotRange -> Automatic, AxesLabel -> {"y", "s"}, 
  Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> {{Line, Magenta}, {Line, Blue}}, 
  PlotLegends -> Placed[{"k1 = 5 ", "k1 = 10 "}, Center]]
 ]


Here is a simplified version of s = s1 + s2:
(s1[y] + s2[y]) /. dsol // FullSimplify
(*
((k1 + eps k2) sf Sinh[k1 - h k1 + k2 (h - y)] + 
   2 (k1 ss + k1 sd Cosh[k1 - h k1] + Q Sinh[k1 - h k1]) Sinh[k2 y] + 
   2 eps k2 sf Sinh[k1 - k1 y] + 2 Q Sinh[h k2] Sinh[k1 - k1 y] - 
   eps k2 sd Sinh[k1 - h k2 - k1 y] - k1 ss Sinh[h k1 - h k2 - k1 y] -
    eps k2 ss Sinh[h k1 - h k2 - k1 y] - 
   eps k2 sd Sinh[k1 + h k2 - k1 y] + k1 ss Sinh[h (k1 + k2) - k1 y] -
    eps k2 ss Sinh[h (k1 + k2) - k1 y] + (-k1 + eps k2) sf Sinh[
     k1 - h k1 - h k2 + k2 y])/(2 (eps k2 Cosh[h k2] Sinh[k1 - h k1] +
      k1 Cosh[k1 - h k1] Sinh[h k2]))
*)


Thank you for your answer. Actually I want to plot s2(y) over 0<y<h and s1(y) over h<y<1 in a single graph. Could you please help me on the same.

@Dr.B.Mallick You're welcome. Plot Piecewise[{{s2[y], 0 < y < h}}, s1[y]] /. dsol over {y, 0, 1} is one way. You could also plot each function over each domain and combine the plots with Show[plot2, plot1, PlotRange -> All]. You usually have to add PlotRange -> All.
